# How do I customize the message that comes up on running AppleScript from within my app

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, applescript, swift4

I am creating a macOS app that needs to execute AppleScript on other apps

Consider the following snippet.

```
let myAppleScript = "tell application \"Finder\" to close window 1 where name is \"Documents\""

var error: NSDictionary?
if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: myAppleScript) {
    let output = scriptObject.executeAndReturnError(&error)
    print("AppleScript output: ", output.stringValue ?? "")
}
```

The first time this gets executed, macOS raises a prompt/dialog with the following message

```
“Xcode“ wants access to control “Finder“. Allowing control will provide access to documents and data in “Finder“, and to perform actions within that app.
```

(`Xcode` will of course get replaced by the name of my app when I run my app directly - currently I am testing the app from within Xcode.)

**I want add another line to this message informing the user why my app needs this permission.** 
How can I do that? (I have seen another app do this, so I know it is possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a key-value pair in Info.plist

- In Source Code view add

  ```
  <key>NSAppleEventsUsageDescription</key>
  <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs to control Finder</string>
  ```
- In Property List view add

  `Privacy - AppleEvents Sending Usage Description`.

The string `value` is the message which is shown to the user.

Comment: If the key is not provided Right-click on Info.plist in the navigation side bar > Open As > Source Code and add the key-value pair manually.